# How to map user profile property to managed property

Tags: user-profile, enterprise-search, managed-property

I have created a user profile property of type string and i pick a term set for this property. How to map this user profile property to managed property in order to search work?

Answer (score 0):

This should be very easy.

When you create the custom user profile property you have to make it "searchable"

[image: search setting user profile property]

After this you can crawl the people data in your search service application. The search will create a so called "crawled property". You have to map this crawled property to a managed property. After this the custom user profile property should be visible in the search center - but only if you display template/xslt render this property.

If you need further instructions please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For a user profile property to become a crawled property, it is important that in the user profile service > Manage User Properties > Edit user profile property the policy settings > Default privacy setting is set to 'Everyone'.

Else, no one but you will be able to retrieve the value, thus not being able to map it to a managed property

Answer (score -1):

You could create another column that is a managed property and copy the values into it.